# realizing pure simplicial complexes in $3$-space

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-complexity, simplicial-complex

Recall that an *abstract simplicial complex* is a family $AS$ of non-empty  finite sets over a ground set $V = \bigcup AS$ which is closed under taking non-empty subsets.
We say $AS$ is *pure* when the inclusion-wise maximal sets of $AS$ all have the same number of elements.

I want to ask two very related questions about realizations. For this I need the following definition:
A *crossing-free* drawing of $AS$ is a point $p_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for each $i \in V$ such that the following holds.
For any pair of sets $\sigma_1,\sigma_2 \in AS$ there is an affine functional $f(x) = \left< a,x \right> +b$ such that 
$f(p_i) \leq 0$ for all $i \in \sigma_1$ and 
$f(p_j) \geq 0$ for all $j \in \sigma_2$.
Furthermore, each tetrahedra(simplex of 4 points) should have positive volume.

**QUESTION1:** What is the algorithmic complexity of deciding if a given abstract simplicial complex can be drawn in $3$-space?

**QUESTION2:**
What is the complexity of deciding if an abstract simplicial complex
can be realized as a simplicial complex in 3-space?

In the second question, we really want each face to be in general position and two faces are either disjoint or they share a face.

thanks
Till

Comment: That's a very strange definition. For instance, the constant map would satisfy this assumption (just take $f$ to be identically zero).

Comment: That is a good point. I guess we want each simplex to be in general position. I added this to the problem description.

Comment: This did not really fix the problem: What if your complex is 2-dimensional. Do you still allow constant maps?

Comment: hmm that would be easy instances. So yes that would be no problem to allow a constant map here. It does not help for the 3-dimensional complexes, which are the interesting ones.